# Retrieving Uid's from Firebase Database

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am currently working on a chatting app. My objective is to get the particular id(marked in the picture)on clicking on that username and display it in the logcat.

This images depicts the values to be retrieved.
[image]

Here is the ViewHolder class and Adapter class for the recycler View.

```
public class UsersAdapterClass extends RecyclerView.Adapter<UsersAdapterClass.UsersViewHolder>{
    Context context;
    List<Users> usersList;
    FirebaseDatabase firebaseDatabase;
    DatabaseReference db;
    public UsersAdapterClass(Context context, List<Users> usersList) {
        this.context = context;
        this.usersList = usersList;
    }

    @Override
    public UsersViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.users_single_layout,parent,false);
        UsersViewHolder usersViewHolder = new UsersViewHolder(view);
        return usersViewHolder;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(UsersViewHolder holder, int position) {
        Users users =  usersList.get(position);
        holder.name.setText(users.getName());
        holder.status.setText(users.getStatus());
        holder.itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                firebaseDatabase= FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
                db = firebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Users");
                final String firebaseId2 = db.push().getKey();
                Log.d("User ID",firebaseId2);
            }
        });

    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return usersList.size();
    }

    public class UsersViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{

        CircleImageView image;
        TextView name,status;

        public UsersViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            image = itemView.findViewById(R.id.circleImageView);
            name = itemView.findViewById(R.id.users_displayname);
            status = itemView.findViewById(R.id.users_status);
        }

        public CircleImageView getImage() {
            return image;
        }
    }
}
```

Also this is the code for class which holds the recycler View.

```
public class UsersMainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private Toolbar mToolbar;
    RecyclerView mRecyclerView;
    UsersAdapterClass adapter;
    private DatabaseReference mUserDatabase;
    List<Users> usersList;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_users_main);
        mToolbar = findViewById(R.id.allusers_appbar);
        mRecyclerView = findViewById(R.id.allusers_recyclerView);
        setSupportActionBar(mToolbar);
        getSupportActionBar().setTitle("All users");
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        mRecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
        mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
        mUserDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Users");

        usersList = new ArrayList<>();

        DatabaseReference dbUsers = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Users");
        dbUsers.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

                if(dataSnapshot.exists())
                {
                    for(DataSnapshot userSnapshot:dataSnapshot.getChildren())
                    {
                        Users u = userSnapshot.getValue(Users.class);
                        usersList.add(u);
                    }
                    adapter = new UsersAdapterClass(UsersMainActivity.this,usersList);
                    mRecyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);

                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });    
    }
}
```

Comment: What error were you getting?

Comment: All the users are displayed in the recycler view, I want to retrieve the id of the user on which I click on. eg: I click on the user 6. I want to get his corresponding uid.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Base on the structure of your Database, the User ids will become the key when you loop through the received snapshot. To get the keys, simply call `getKey()` on your looped datasnapshot. You can do that by adding below code in between your loop and log it to your Logcat...

```
String userIds = userSnapshot.getKey(); //Get keys
Log.d("USERID KEYS", userIds) //Log to logcat
```

**EDIT:** Create a **getter** and **setter** for the User id in your `User` model/POJO. Then pass the `userIds` to the setter. For instance `u.setUserId(userIds)`. Now in your adapter, simply get the `userid` in your `onclick()`

```
...
     @Override
     public void onClick(View v) {

         Log.d("User ID",user.getUserId());
    }
...
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. As all the users are displayed in the recycler view, I want to retrieve the id of the user on which I click on. eg: I click on the user 6. I want to get his corresponding uid. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I've done some modification on my answer. Let me know if you still need some help.

Comment: Thanks mate. That was exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: You're welcome. Upvote and accept it as the right answer if it solved your issue. Cheers!

Comment: Also wanted a little more help. I want to retrieve the images stored in the database to the recycler view. How to do it???

Comment: You have to accept this first as the right answer, then create another post your new issue.

Answer (score 0):

Inside your onBindViewHolder you can store the uids in a string this way

final String userIds = getRef(position).getKey();